# Magento 2 In the UI form, Edit urlInput is not working properly

Tags: magento2, url, ui-form, edit, input

I've created a UI form with a URLInput field. For creating new entries, it works fine. However, the 'open in new tab' setting is always checked in the edit form. The value has been binded correctly. In edit, all other fields work as expected.
[image]
Here is my code in ui form

```
  <urlInput name="link">
        <settings>
            <dataType>text</dataType>
            <label translate="true">Link</label>
            <dataScope>link</dataScope>
            <isDisplayAdditionalSettings>true</isDisplayAdditionalSettings>
            <settingValue>false</settingValue>
            <urlTypes class="Magento\Ui\Model\UrlInput\LinksConfigProvider"/>
            <validation>
                <rule name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">false</rule>
            </validation>
        </settings>
    </urlInput>
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
<urlInput name="link">
    <settings>
        <dataType>text</dataType>
        <label translate="true">Link</label>
        <dataScope>link</dataScope> 
        <settingTemplate>ui/form/element/urlInput/setting</settingTemplate>
        <typeSelectorTemplate>ui/form/element/urlInput/typeSelector</typeSelectorTemplate>
        <isDisplayAdditionalSettings>true</isDisplayAdditionalSettings>
        <settingValue>false</settingValue>
        <urlTypes class="Magento\Ui\Model\UrlInput\LinksConfigProvider"/>
        <validation>
            <rule name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">false</rule>
        </validation>
    </settings>
</urlInput>
```

**UPDATE:**

```
<urlInput name="link" sortOrder="20" template="Magento_PageBuilder/form/element/url-input">
    <settings>
        <dataType>text</dataType>
        <label translate="true">Link</label>
        <dataScope>link_url</dataScope>
        <urlTypes class="Magento\Ui\Model\UrlInput\LinksConfigProvider"/>
        <isDisplayAdditionalSettings>true</isDisplayAdditionalSettings>
        <settingValue>false</settingValue>
        <urlTypes class="Magento\Ui\Model\UrlInput\LinksConfigProvider"/>
        <validation>
            <rule name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">false</rule>
        </validation>
    </settings>
</urlInput>
```

Comment: I've tried it, but it didn't work.

Comment: Updated please try once again

Comment: Still it is not working